# using .net framework to develop cocoa application

Tags: c#, objective-c, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

thanks for reading this and helping.
I am comp sci intern, I mostly code winform applications using C# .net framework on windows. Recently, for job requirement, I have to make an application on Mac OS, which could be opened by just one doubleclicking the application. No script, command line or anything.
I research a bit about MONO and I successfully wrote an applescript application to do shell script and mono the Winform application. It does the works just like it does on windows, but the thing is it does the works very slowly on Mac. Therefore, I look more into Xamarin.Mac, and started learning to make a cocoa application.
However, here comes the question. If in the cocoa application, I still use the .net framework stuffs like List, Linq, System.IO like File.WriteAllLines instead of native cocoa stuff like NSMutableArray, NSFileManager, would it be slow just like MONO the Winform application?
Hypothetically, if I wrote pure objective-c in Xamarin comparing pure .net stuff to do the same job, would the .net one run slower than the objective-c one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoMac was the framework (open source) to develop desktop OS X applications (32 bit). But it is now obsolete in favor of the commercial Xamarin.Mac platform (32 bit/64 bit).

If you are still a student, please get academic licenses from Xamarin,

http://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-students/

The difficulty is that whether you can later find an employer that embraces Xamarin platforms. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you introduce an abstraction layer into your app it's going to be slower than native code. Whether or not that's a trade off you're comfortable with is up to you.

Comment: but what if xamarin somehow makes all .net stuff into objective-c during the compilation, then when the app runs, it wouldn't be slow.